# Solve this limit when $n$ tend to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

my name is Agapita and I don't know what I am wrong in this exercise:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(4^{n+1}-n^{10})}{(n^8+4^n)}$$

What I have done so far is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(4^n\cdot4^1)-n^{10}}{n^8+4^n}$$

Now I divide everything by $4^n$:

$$\lim \frac{(4^n\cdot 4^1)/4^n-n^{10}/4^n}{(n^8/4^n+4^n/4^n)}=$$

$$=\frac{1\cdot 0-0}{0+1}= 0/1 = 0$$

But the answer to this problem is actually $4$.
Could anyone help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: $4^n*4^1/4^n=1*4$ not $1*0$

Comment: Sorry, I've explained myself wrong. I alredy edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4^{n+1}-n^{10}}{n^8+4^n}
$$
then you divide the argument by $4^n$ which gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{
\frac{
 4\cdot4^n}{4^n}-
\frac{n^{10}}
{4^n}}{\frac{n^8}{4^n}+\frac{4^n}{4^n}}
$$
which reduces to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{
4-
\frac{n^{10}}
{4^n}}{\frac{n^8}{4^n}+1}
$$
finally letting $n$ tend to infinity we get
$$
\frac{4}{1}=4
$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the last row.
When you divide
$$
4\cdot 4^{n}
$$
with $4^n$ you end up with
$$
4\cdot 1
$$
So the last line looks like
$$
  \frac{4\cdot 1-0}{0+1}
$$
which gives the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how $4/4^n$ = 1 :/

Comment: let me edit my answer to give you a full picture. I just ususally try to give hints instead of full solutions

Comment: @Agapita Since when is $\frac{ab}{c}=\frac ac\frac bc$ ? It kind of never holds.

Comment: only when $c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In last step, I think $4^{n} \cdot 4 / 4^n$ is $\frac{4^n \cdot4}{4^n} = \frac{4^n}{4^n}\cdot4 = 4$